# Concatenating Integer to String Works without TO_CHAR in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, concatenation, sqldatatypes

I'm curious why an integer can be concatenated to a string without using `TO_CHAR`, like shown in the following example:

```
declare
    type test_table is table of varchar2(20);

    test_session   test_table;
begin
    with
        sessions
        as
            (select 1 session_num from dual
             union
             select 2 session_num from dual),
        session_concat
        as
            (select 'Session: ' || session_num
             from dual, sessions)
    select *
    bulk collect into test_session
    from session_concat;
end;
/
```

The concatenation also works with the `CONCAT` keyword instead of `||` operator and furthermore when an integer variable is declared and concatenated (rather than selecting `FROM DUAL`).

Comment: I believe this is an 'implicit' conversion, Oracle, and MSSQL, will automatically convert primitive types to the destination data type. Be careful with these as the behavior is not always predictable, especially in where clauses. A google search for implicit conversion should help you to understand this.

Comment: Thanks. I found the documentation for Oracle implicit conversions. Thanks for the tip--I always use `TO_CHAR` to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of Oracle performing an [implicit data conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm).

It is best practice to perform explicit data type conversions (for reasons discussed in the comments to this post and on the linked Oracle documentation page).